# What is this element and how can I click on it?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using webdriver with c# and I need to click on the "select all" menu inside a Google document.  Here is the line of code:

```
<span aria-label="Select all, a;" class="goog-menuitem-label" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">Select <span class="goog-menuitem-mnemonic-hint" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">a</span>ll</span>
```

What I would like to do is :

**Number 1.  Find the span element** 
**Number 2.  Click on the span element**

I'm struggling to find the span element because I don't know what code I need to even find this span element.  As far as I can tell, I can't see a way of selecting a "span" element using the "By" locators.  I have Id, ClassName, TagName, etc.  I've tried these but they (obvious for some) don't work.

p.s I need to avoid the sendkeys method

Many thanks.  Appreciate the help

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Besides, what do you mean, "what is this element"? It's a `span` element.

Comment: Ok great. So how then would I find this span element where text contains "X" ?

Comment: You haven't really told us what problem you're having. How do you find other elements? Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Again, it is a `<span>` element. You can locate it using any number of locators. What locators aren't working for you? Edit your post above to show what you have tried and what hasn't worked and include any stacktraces. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use either xpath or css selector. These are a little more complex but allow you to find elements that are not easily selected if they are missing IDs or similar.

xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='goog-menuitem-labal']"));
```

css

```
driver.findElememt(By.cssSelector("span.goog-menu-item-label"));
```